# Apple certificate fail to upload in Azure Notification Hub (long path)

Tags: azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

I have an issue with uploading a renewed Apple push certificate for a Azure Notification Hub. It states that the path is to long.

Error updating notification hub:

```
{"error":{"message":"The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.","code":"InternalServerError"}}
```

I do not understand how such a error is relevant to an Azure service. All the solutions to this problem pertains to changing the folder reference to a shorter name in a config file (web projects). The web project itself is on another instance.

Comment: According to your description, it seems that the error was thrown when you uploading your p12 file via Azure Portal. What is the name of your p12 file, have you tried to create a new notification hub to narrow this issue?

Comment: Hi Bruce. I agree that the error is linked with the upload. Have tried changing the name to a single letter, a.p12, without success. Creating a new notification hub did not work either.

Comment: Almost seems like a bug on Azure Portal Side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there was an issue with this. The Notification Hubs team has now fixed it.